# EF Core Why Do Migrations need names?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

What is the point in given migrations names?

```
dotnet ef migrations add {MigrationName}
```

The file that it generates seems to start with the timestamp the migration was create, so whats the value of the name?

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason source control usually requires commit messages--to help developers differentiate between them.

The `dotnet ef migrations add` command is always going to require a name, but you could override the internal `IMigrationsIdGenerator` to ignore it and just use the timestamp.

But since you have to specify them anyway, you might as well just use a sequence like `M1`, `M2`... if you don't feel they're important.

Answer (score 0):

because that name gets store for possible rollback.

Also, with the command posted it has NOTHING to do with entityframework below 6.3

reference table _EntityMigration in your database...